# $d_1(x,y)<d(x,y)\Rightarrow \{x|d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}\subset \{x|d_1(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$

Tags: metric-spaces

Can someone please give me a hint why for metric spaces we have

$d_1(x,y)<d(x,y)\Rightarrow \{x|d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}\subset \{x|d_1(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$

I have expected the opposite:

$d_1(x,y)<d(x,y)\Rightarrow \{x|d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}\supset \{x|d_1(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it is a matter of precision, think that $x$ and $y$ are points and $d_1$ is the distance in centimeters and $d$ is in millimeters, so numerically we have $d1 <d$, and every measure using $d$ is therefore more accurate ...

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, this goes in the right direction. Can you explain this more using $\mathbb{R}^2$. What does this mean in the space?

Comment: Maybe this is a reason why $d$ can "see" more points?

Comment: In the book Espaços métricos, LIMA, EL this is a matter of equivalent metrics, where one is thinner than the other, and this can occur in any set M that supports injective distance functions, that is, $(M, d) \rightarrow ( M, d_1)$

Answer (score 2):

Because if $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$, then $d_1(x,y)<d(x,y)<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we claim that $\{x:d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}\subset \{x:d_1(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$. Indeed, let $x_0 \in \{x:d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$ then, $d(x_0,y)<\varepsilon$. Since $d_1(x_0,y)<d(x_0,y)$ we obtain $d_1(x_0,y)<\varepsilon$, that is, $x_0 \in \{x: d_1(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$